# counting rows matching criteria in mysql join , union >= and <=?

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

```
Select * FROM table WHERE a<=9 AND a>=4 AND b<=20 AND b>=16 AND c<=30 AND c>=26
```

Now I want to end up selecting from query 1 the results in which at least two of the following criteria are met.

```
Select * FROM table WHERE a<=7 AND a>=5 AND B<=19 AND B>=17 AND C<=29 AND c>=27
```

Numbers could be anything, although on query 2 these are lower for the less than eqaul and higher for the bigger than equal.

I want to be able to set the number of minimum coincidences to be met at query 2 with a number.
For example 5 coincidences must be met at query 2 to end up making a selection in query 1.

This is about range and matches count, if there is an easier way to achieve this great.

Comment: If your lower bound is always higher and your higher bound is always lower (in the second query), the first query is redundant.

Comment: No, because I want to make a subselect from the second query, all positive matches in query 1, but a specified amount of matches in the second query.

Comment: Sorry, can you please tell us more about the result you want. I don't understand.  Also, tell us what columns are in your table.

Comment: Basically I want to get with a number, say 5 if it is match between records that have a value in between 3 and 7,sort of a range, I'd like to select all the values in between 3 and 7 but on a second query, as the numbers to select are many what I want is to find occurrences which are closer to 5 in a different range other than 2,a lower range, say 1, so I would check for 5<=6 AND 5>=4, positive on query 2. Say 70 numbers on query 1, all positive matches using a range of 2, well now I want at least out of those 70, 50 matches with a lowest range in the first 70 analysed. @ruakh b<=20 AND b>=16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this kind of query will do your job

```
Select 
*,
(IF(a<=7 AND a>=5,1,0) + IF(B<=19 AND B>=17,1,0) + IF(C<=29 AND c>=27,1,0))
as totalmatch
FROM table
HAVING totalmatch >=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native MySQL function [BEETWEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE key_col BETWEEN '2' AND '3';
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it is something like this you want for the second query:-

```
Select *, CASE WHEN a<=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN  a>=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN B<=19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN B>=17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN C<=29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN c>=27 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchCount
FROM table 
WHERE a<=7 
OR a>=5 
OR B<=19 
OR B>=17 
OR C<=29 
OR c>=27
HAVING MatchCount >= 2
```

Probably using the first query as a subselect instead of table.

EDIT - reading your latest response I think I misunderstood your requirement. However you could possibly find the differences between each values, get the absolute value of each difference and add them together to see how close / far the differences are.